# Spring AMQP Multiple Users

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a multi user application that I had incorporated Spring AMQP to do messaging to my RabbitMQ server, after testing different users I noticed that simultaneous logins on different account would cause other users to intercept messages, not only that but when no one is logged in the application is still grabbing messages. I realized that I probably needed to set a vHost for each user and make sure that AMQP didn't auto connect...

which is where my question comes in, how exactly are you supposed to do that?

I am using the JAVA config version and ditched the XML to make it easier but it has really not. I've tried closing and destroying the SimpleMessageListener, using the RabbitUtil to try and close the connection when the user logs out, then try to use createConnection when they log back in but all of that either doesn't work or causes an exception. I set autoStartup to false which seems to work, but as soon as someone logs in that goes out the window. And that is only half the problem, if I could do all that I could probably figure out the vHosts but this is the bigger issue of the two since it makes that irrelevant.

At this point I am wondering if it even made to be used concurrently by a multi user application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide much more information, including what you are doing with rabbit, and configuration.

However, you likely don't need a vhost per user you just need to use separate queue(s) per user - declare them on-demand, route to them with dynamic routing keys; add/remove them from the listener container etc, etc.